# How to sort string array in descending order in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sorting, scripting

let's say I have an array:

`nameArr=("Leia", "Darth Vader", "Anakin", "Han Solo", "Yoda")`

and I would like to sort in descending order. How could I do it in Bash shell scripting? In ascending order I am using command:

`arrAsc=($(for l in ${nameArr[@]}; do echo $l; done | sort))`

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Try `sort -r` to reverse order.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also write `arr=($(printf '%s\n' "${nameArr[@]}" | sort -r))
`

Comment: i would say it does not matter because the complexity should be the same. Am I right?

Comment: the `printf '%s\n' ${arr[@]}` is just a good reminder that it will process all values one-by-one from the input string, replacing a `for` loop for (in this case), the same functionality. (Think how easy extending this to process 2 words at a time with `printf` would be). You can also go for the idea that the shortest code wins ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @chepner How is sorting an array of strings non-trivial? Plus, you can do amazing and fun things with bash if you know how to use it

Comment: @JeffreyCash I didn't say sorting was non-trivial; I implied that `bash` was the wrong language to be using if you needed to sort a list of strings. Just because you *can* do something in `bash` (it's Turing-complete, after all) doesn't mean you *should*. Your answer, by the way, indirectly supports my point. You didn't sort the strings in `bash`; you filtered the unsorted list through a program written in C (`sort`).

Comment: @chepner You're being a pedant. He asked how he could sort a _bash_ array of strings of strings in "_Bash_ shell scripting". You replied that you wouldn't; I was actually helpful and answered the question with a method of sorting an array in bash. Bash is incredibly useful and OP seems new to bash, so why wouldn't you want to help the guy out?

Comment: I *am* helping him. He appears to be using `bash` as a general purpose language, and in my experience any program that starts needing to do general data processing, rather than simply acting as glue to run other programs together, eventually needs to be rewritten in a more suitable language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so fairly easily making use of `IFS` (*internal field separator*), `sort -r`, and a little help from `printf`. Using *command substitution* you can output and sort the array and then simply read the sorted results back into `nameArr`. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

nameArr=("Leia", "Darth Vader", "Anakin", "Han Solo", "Yoda")

IFS=$'\n'           ## only word-split on '\n'
nameArr=( $(printf "%s\n" ${nameArr[@]} | sort -r ) )  ## reverse sort

declare -p nameArr  ## simply output the array
```

**Example Use/Output**

Calling the script results in the following:

```
$ bash revarr.sh
declare -a nameArr='([0]="Yoda" [1]="Leia," [2]="Han Solo," [3]="Darth Vader," [4]="Anakin,")'
```

***note:*** don't forget to restore the default `IFS=$' \t\n'` (`space`, `tab`, `newline`) when done with the sort if your script continues.

Answer (score 1):

Your question inspired me to whip up a function that I'm sure will come in handy in the future:

`sort_array () { local v="$1[*]" IFS=$'\n'; read -d $'\0' -a "$1" < <(sort "${@:2}" <<< "${!v}"); }`

Usage: sort_array NameOfArrayVariable [flags to pass to sort command]

With `nameArr=("Leia", "Darth Vader", "Anakin", "Han Solo", "Yoda")`:
calling `sort_array nameArr` will result in nameArr containing ("Anakin," "Darth Vader," "Han Solo," "Leia," "Yoda"); calling `sort_array nameArr -r` will result in nameArr containing ("Yoda" "Leia," "Han Solo," "Darth Vader," "Anakin,")

Also, just a heads up, when you declare or set an array in bash, you do not comma separate elements, as `"Leia",` is the same as `"Leia,"` unless you set IFS to contain a comma.

This function also works well with integer arrays:

```
$ nums=()
$ for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do nums+=($RANDOM); done
$ echo "${nums[@]}";
22928 7011 18865 24027 18559 9037 3885 10873 32369 21932
$ sort_array nums -n
$ echo "${nums[@]}"
3885 7011 9037 10873 18559 18865 21932 22928 24027 32369
$ sort_array nums -nr 
$ echo "${nums[@]}"
32369 24027 22928 21932 18865 18559 10873 9037 7011 3885
```